# Android push plugin getting registered but not receiving any message

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

I am implementing push-plugin notifications for android in my app , For that i followed several tutorials before actually implementing the phonegap push plugin for android in my app

Step 1 ) I got a sample code from GCM site under samples and created a "Sample APP". it's working with a tomcat server i.e. i am able to register>> receive those registration ids at backend>> store them in mysql >> send messages to each of the registered id's

Step 2 ) Then i tried to use the phonegap push plugin for android in my "Main app". Although it's able to register the app with gcm (getting register Id)I am not able to connect to my backend tomcat server (same as above, with same Sender Id), even i tried to create a sample regid in mysql and then push messages to the regId but the messages are not received on the devices , although "sample app" of Step 1 is still receiving messages from Tomcat Server

Here is my code for main app **AndroidManifest.xml**
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.votesapp.phonegap"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.plugin.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.plugin.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="VotesApp"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.plugin.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

</manifest>
```

`

**CordovaGCMBroadCastReceiver.java**

```
 package com.plugin.gcm;

import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;

/*
 * Implementation of GCMBroadcastReceiver that hard-wires the intent service to be 
 * com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService, instead of your_package.GCMIntentService 
 */
public class CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        return "com.plugin.gcm" + DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;
    }

}
```

**GCMIntentService.java**

```
  package com.plugin.gcm;

    import android.content.Context;

    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;
    import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;

    /*
     * Implementation of GCMBroadcastReceiver that hard-wires the intent service to be 
     * com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService, instead of your_package.GCMIntentService 
     */
    public class CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
            return "com.plugin.gcm" + DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;
        }


}
```

**PushHandlerActivity.java**

```
package com.plugin.gcm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class PushHandlerActivity extends Activity
{
    private static String TAG = "PushHandlerActivity"; 

    /*
     * this activity will be started if the user touches a notification that we own. 
     * We send it's data off to the push plugin for processing.
     * If needed, we boot up the main activity to kickstart the application. 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");

        boolean isPushPluginActive = PushPlugin.isActive();
        processPushBundle(isPushPluginActive);

        GCMIntentService.cancelNotification(this);

        finish();

        if (!isPushPluginActive) {
            forceMainActivityReload();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes the pushBundle extras from the intent, 
     * and sends it through to the PushPlugin for processing.
     */
    private void processPushBundle(boolean isPushPluginActive)
    {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            Bundle originalExtras = extras.getBundle("pushBundle");

            originalExtras.putBoolean("foreground", false);
            originalExtras.putBoolean("coldstart", !isPushPluginActive);

            PushPlugin.sendExtras(originalExtras);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Forces the main activity to re-launch if it's unloaded.
     */
    private void forceMainActivityReload()
    {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());           
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }

}
```

**PushPlugin.java**

```
package com.plugin.gcm;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

import com.google.android.gcm.*;

/**
 * @author awysocki
 */

public class PushPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public static final String TAG = "PushPlugin";

    public static final String REGISTER = "register";
    public static final String UNREGISTER = "unregister";
    public static final String EXIT = "exit";

    private static CordovaWebView gWebView;
    private static String gECB;
    private static String gSenderID;
    private static Bundle gCachedExtras = null;
    private static boolean gForeground = false;

    /**
     * Gets the application context from cordova's main activity.
     * @return the application context
     */
    private Context getApplicationContext() {
        return this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        boolean result = false;

        Log.v(TAG, "execute: action=" + action);

        if (REGISTER.equals(action)) {

            Log.v(TAG, "execute: data=" + data.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jo = data.getJSONObject(0);

                gWebView = this.webView;
                Log.v(TAG, "execute: jo=" + jo.toString());

                gECB = (String) jo.get("ecb");
                gSenderID = (String) jo.get("senderID");

                Log.v(TAG, "execute: ECB=" + gECB + " senderID=" + gSenderID);

                GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), gSenderID);
                result = true;
                callbackContext.success();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "execute: Got JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                result = false;
                callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            }

            if ( gCachedExtras != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "sending cached extras");
                sendExtras(gCachedExtras);
                gCachedExtras = null;
            }

        } else if (UNREGISTER.equals(action)) {

            GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());

            Log.v(TAG, "UNREGISTER");
            result = true;
            callbackContext.success();
        } else {
            result = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid action : " + action);
            callbackContext.error("Invalid action : " + action);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /*
     * Sends a json object to the client as parameter to a method which is defined in gECB.
     */
    public static void sendJavascript(JSONObject _json) {
        String _d = "javascript:" + gECB + "(" + _json.toString() + ")";
        Log.v(TAG, "sendJavascript: " + _d);

        if (gECB != null && gWebView != null) {
            gWebView.sendJavascript(_d); 
        }
    }

    /*
     * Sends the pushbundle extras to the client application.
     * If the client application isn't currently active, it is cached for later processing.
     */
    public static void sendExtras(Bundle extras)
    {
        if (extras != null) {
            if (gECB != null && gWebView != null) {
                sendJavascript(convertBundleToJson(extras));
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "sendExtras: caching extras to send at a later time.");
                gCachedExtras = extras;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        gForeground = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(boolean multitasking) {
        super.onPause(multitasking);
        gForeground = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {
        super.onResume(multitasking);
        gForeground = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        gForeground = false;
        gECB = null;
        gWebView = null;
    }

    /*
     * serializes a bundle to JSON.
     */
    private static JSONObject convertBundleToJson(Bundle extras)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject json;
            json = new JSONObject().put("event", "message");

            JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject();
            Iterator<String> it = extras.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                String key = it.next();
                Object value = extras.get(key); 

                // System data from Android
                if (key.equals("from") || key.equals("collapse_key"))
                {
                    json.put(key, value);
                }
                else if (key.equals("foreground"))
                {
                    json.put(key, extras.getBoolean("foreground"));
                }
                else if (key.equals("coldstart"))
                {
                    json.put(key, extras.getBoolean("coldstart"));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Maintain backwards compatibility
                    if (key.equals("message") || key.equals("msgcnt") || key.equals("soundname"))
                    {
                        json.put(key, value);
                    }

                    if ( value instanceof String ) {
                    // Try to figure out if the value is another JSON object

                        String strValue = (String)value;
                        if (strValue.startsWith("{")) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(strValue);
                                jsondata.put(key, json2);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                jsondata.put(key, value);
                            }
                            // Try to figure out if the value is another JSON array
                        }
                        else if (strValue.startsWith("["))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                JSONArray json2 = new JSONArray(strValue);
                                jsondata.put(key, json2);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                jsondata.put(key, value);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            jsondata.put(key, value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } // while
            json.put("payload", jsondata);

            Log.v(TAG, "extrasToJSON: " + json.toString());

            return json;
        }
        catch( JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "extrasToJSON: JSON exception");
        }           
        return null;        
    }

    public static boolean isInForeground()
    {
      return gForeground;
    }

    public static boolean isActive()
    {
        return gWebView != null;
    }
}
```

the code is as it is from the phonegap push plugin github repository, Please help or suggest me few things which i can try it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your GCMIntentService class in the main packgae define in manifest tag.

Comment: @Meenal : Thanks for your reply!! I saw that i didn't implemented any code to register to the server , now i have implemented that and my app is registering with server but now I am not able to receive any notifications ,,, why is that so ??

Comment: You shouldn't post open source code without the license to stack overflow. It makes it appear to be public domain. Instead, just link to the github files.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I solved the problem my self by adding an explicit call to the server in the event call back function (ECB) in the onNotificationGCM(ecb) javascript method provided by "Notifcations by phonegap push-plugin for Android"  and now I am able to receive the notifications in the foreground and background

```
var theUrl = new String("http://<yourUrl>:8080?regId="+e.regid+"&userName=xyz");

                            var xmlHttp = null;

                            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
                            xmlHttp.send( null );
                            alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

I also learned that CordovaGCMBroadCastReceiver and GCMIntentService should be "together" and in the main package (the package that is specified in the mainfest tag) , the reason being when there is a multicast(non collapsing) for the same device , multiple threads will be created for sending messages to the same device and then either of them will go for acquiring a wakelock arising a situation of deadlock, this was relased when i moved both my CordovaGCMBroadCastReceiver and GCMIntentService to my main package i.e. from com.plugin.gcm to com.votesapp.phonegap (the package mentioned in my manifest tag). Now i am able to receive multiple notifications to the same device.

**Note : This solution is specific to phonegap push plugin code**

Answer (score 0):

@user2845335 I followed your same steps. 
I get the registration id in an alert. GCM is registered on google. 
Sending messages to the device works perfectly, if you recall the file on the server http://www.mydomain.com/index.php

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>GCM</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $con = mysql_connect("x.x.x.x", "Sqlxxxx","xxxxxxx");
   if(!$con){
    die('MySQL connection failed');
   }

   $db = mysql_select_db("Sqlxxxx");
   if(!$db){
    die('Database selection failed');
   }


   $registatoin_ids = array();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM android_udid";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($registatoin_ids, $row['registration_id']);
   }

   // Set POST variables
   $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

   $message = array("message" => $_POST['message']);
       $fields = array(
           'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
           'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
             'Authorization: key=mykey',
             'Content-Type: application/json'
         );
         // Open connection
         $ch = curl_init();

         // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

         // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

         // Execute post
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         if ($result === FALSE) {
             die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
         }

         // Close connection
         curl_close($ch);
         echo $result;

  }
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
  <label>Insert Message: </label><input type="text" name="message" />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
 <?php
if (isset($fields)) {
print_r($fields);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

what I still can not do, is to store on mysql id registration

```
<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
        var name=$("#name").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "http://www.mydomain.com/register.php",
    data:...

</script>
```

Comment: Some more scenarios to check                                             a)put a alert in onNotification of method that whether it's being called or not.                                                              b)check whether you are able to access the Server URL outside say from a different computer or say browser of mobile.

Comment: @user2845335 i checked a) Yes, onNotification returns the registration id (but this way is to manually enter in the db)  b) si, si può accedere al server anche da altri device/browser. Thank you again.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Phonegap Push Plugin sample code (added a Note with my answer for that as well when i posted that)                                I can see that you have added the code to call the post method on document ready,, are you sure that is being called after you receive regid?? ,,, See the structure of GCMEventHelper.js and PushNotification.js came with the plugin ,,the onNotificationGCM() method is called after register method has been called in PushNotification.js

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your API key and sender id Replace them with new one

Comment: You can follow this tutorial also for GCM http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/